# how to iterate over dict and convert it to table record in react js using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

having the following structure:

```
history: {
    https://jsonplaceholde.typicode.com/posts/41: "failed",
    https://jsonplaceholde.typicode.com/posts/42: "failed",
}
```

which is accessible via this.state.stats.history

how can I use map to iterate over the history and create table records generate table records?

something like this ->

```
<tr>
    {this.state.stats&& this.state.stats.history.map( ([key, value]) => {<th>key</th><th>value</th>})}
</tr>
```

Comment: you can do a mapping on history. because it object not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of the entries in the object. You'll also need a fragment (or array) since `map` has to have a single value to return.

```
{this.state.stats
    ? Object.entries(this.state.stats.history).map(([key, value]) =>
          <><th>{key}</th><th>{value}</th></>
      )
    : false
}
```

(I pobably wouldn't do this directly in the structure being `return`ed, I'd do it beforehand to avoid too much conditional logic in a JSX expression.